# Why is MCU Thanos inferior to his 616 counterpart?

Tags: marvel, adaptation-comparison, avengers-infinity-war, thanos, the-infinity-gauntlet

In *Thanos: Infinity Gauntlet*, Thanos was extremely powerful with the Infinity Gauntlet, and would no way get severely injured by Thor's stormbreaker. With the IG, he knew what moves people would make before they made them, he was able to turn characters to glass and shatter them (Thor), turn people into essentially Legos (Nova), Shatter Vibranium with his fist (Captain America), turn Quasar's bands against him, and easily create another person who was nearly equal to him in physical strength. Also, the IG was not even remotely damaged when he snapped. Why was the MCU Thanos nearly defeated?

Comment: Not sure this warrants a full answer, but simply: Thanos being an ustoppable force of nature makes for a boring movie, doesn't it?  "Thanos kicks the crap out of everyone" doesn't exactly sell tickets.  Also, the Infinity Gauntlet is very much damaged after The Snap, as seen [here] (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/O5xYqJx2f_k/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: I was saying that in the comic the gaunlet was not damaged; I know that it was nearly destroyed in the film.

Comment: It sounds like you're really asking why the Infinity Gauntlet seems less powerful in *Avengers: Infinity War* than in the original *Infinity Gauntlet* mini-series. From the title, I would think you're asking about the relative power levels of the MCU Thanos and the comics Thanos *without* the Gauntlet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to try to flesh this out into a full answer.  Lots of speculation ahead.

**Bad Movie**

As I stated in the comments, "Thanos Wrecks the MCU" makes for a boring, repetitive movie.  No one is going to want to see that (okay, maybe some people, but not enough to get green-lit by the likes of Disney).  A good movie needs to get audiences emotionally invested, but in order to root for an underdog, they need to have *something* going for them. The MCU accomplishes this by bringing Thanos close to the edge of defeat, showing us that it is *possible* for the combined efforts of the Avengers, the Guardians of the Galaxy, and others to defeat him.

**Different Motives**

Thanos in the comics is almost a different character.  His trail of destruction up to and including The Snap is to win the attention and affection of Mistress Death.  It's all rather...petty, really, but there are different constraints in comics.  You can take a long time to get around to your story arc.  You can drag out a fight for longer before your audience loses interest.

There is no Mistress Death equivalent in the MCU.  Thanos' underlying motives have been established differently - he sees himself as a savior, even if no one else does.  He considers himself the only one with the will to do what needs to be done in order to prevent what he sees as the collapse of civilization.  This is important, because in the comics ***Thanos loses because he doesn't believe he's worthy of power***.  MCU Thanos has no such qualms that we know of - in fact it's almost the exact opposite.

**The Snap and the Gauntlet**

In the comics, Thanos retains the functional Gauntlet after The Snap.  In the movie, the Gauntlet is damaged, which probably serves two purposes.  The first is to make Thanos non-omnipotent again (he's already a formidable opponent in combat, with a still-functioning Gauntlet it would become "Thanos Wills the MCU Out of Existence" pretty quickly).

I'm speculating that it also removes the possibility of an "easy fix" for the heroes.  A damaged Gauntlet maybe can't undo The Snap with Another Snap, so now they have to figure out another solution.  It's possible that the damage will be revealed as something along the lines of "the infinity stones can't be used together again" - we have no real way of knowing.  But I believe the damage to the Gauntlet serves as a visual indicator that what Thanos did was a one-time thing.

Comment: ... until he makes another gauntlet?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier There's no indication that it's possible to make another gauntlet.  Thanos didn't create the first one, and he crippled the Dwarf that made it for him after killing all the other Dwarf smiths.  In addition, making another gauntlet would be counter to Thanos' goal - he's achieved what he wants, why would he make the one thing that can undo his accomplishment?

Comment: There's another thing, he's killed off half the life in the universe, but give the universe a century or two and the population problems will be back to critical levels, surely he'll need to snap on a regular basis. I'm not sure Thanos has thought this through . . .